# How to add average in intervals on the plot

Tags: r, plot

I've got a dataset consisting of dates starting from `2018-04-22T11:48:53` finishing on `2018-04-22T12:03:24`. Every timestamp got its own value. I need to create a function that takes a `data.frame` and based on that draws a plot with real values and average values for each interval.

Comment: by interval i've got in mind for example 60 seconds and the avarege value within this period

Comment: added image, and a few tags

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested *to create a function that takes a data.frame and based on that draws a plot with real values and average values for each interval.*

This is what *I* would do to meet this requirement using `data.table` for aggregation, `scales` for creating "nice" intervals, `ggplot2` for plotting, and `checkmate` for checking input parameters:

```
plot_avg <- function(DF, x_arg, y_arg, interval_width, show_avg = NULL) {
  # check arguments
  checkmate::assert_data_frame(DF, min.rows = 1L, min.cols = 2L, 
                               col.names = "strict")
  checkmate::assert_string(x_arg, min.chars = 1L)
  checkmate::assert_string(y_arg, min.chars = 1L)
  checkmate::assert_subset(c(x_arg, y_arg), names(DF))
  checkmate::assert_number(interval_width, lower = .Machine$double.xmin)
  checkmate::assert_character(show_avg, null.ok = TRUE)
  checkmate::assert_subset(show_avg, c("segm", "step", ""))
  # load required packages
  library(data.table)
  library(ggplot2)
  # compute averages
  breaks <- scales::fullseq(range(DF[[x_arg]]), interval_width)
  aggDT <- as.data.table(DF)[
    , .(avg = mean(get(y_arg))), 
    by = .(start  = breaks[cut(get(x_arg), breaks, right = FALSE, labels = FALSE)])]
  # start plotting
  g <- ggplot(DF) + aes_string(x_arg, y_arg) +
    geom_point(color = "blue") + 
    {if (length(breaks) < 30) scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks)} +
    theme_bw()
  if ("segm" %in% show_avg) 
    g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = start, xend = start + interval_width, 
                              y = avg, yend = avg), aggDT)
  if ("step" %in% show_avg) 
    g <- g + geom_step(aes(start, avg), aggDT, linetype = "dashed")
  # return plot object
  return(g)
}
```

With a sample data set created as described below we can create different plots.

Only data points:

```
plot_avg(DT, "sec", "value", 60L)
```

[image]

With averages as horizontal line segments:

```
plot_avg(DT, "sec", "value", 60L, "segm")
```

[image]

With averages as horizontal line segments plus steps

```
plot_avg(DT, "sec", "value", 60L, c("segm", "step"))
```

[image]

The interval width can be varied:

```
plot_avg(DT, "sec", "value", 20L, c("segm", "step"))
```

[image]

#### Data

The OP has not provided any publically accessible sample data. So, I had to make up my own sample dataset:

```
library(data.table)
secs <- seq(lubridate::ymd_hms("2018-04-22T11:48:53"), 
            lubridate::ymd_hms("2018-04-22T12:03:24"), 
            by = "sec")
n_secs <- length(secs)
n_row <- as.integer(n_secs / 10)
set.seed(0)
DT <- data.table(times = sort(sample(secs, n_row)))
DT[, sec := as.integer(times - min(times))]
f <- 2*pi/n_secs
DT[, value := cos(f*sec) + sin(2*f*sec) + 0.1 * rnorm(.N)]
```